# Pushing files to origin repo

Tags: git, server, development-environment

I'm just starting with Git today, so sorry if this is a super basic question. I just can't seem to wrap my head around all these new terms enough to get my configuration set up. 
I have 2 servers: remote and local. Remote is a netork location where the site i'm working on needs to reside; it is also shared with colleagues. local is a folder on my machine's iis webserver.

I have created a repo on my remote server. This is where the files need to 'live', so i have not used `init --bare`. I committed the initial configuration. I then created a clone of that repo on my local machine which I will use as my local workarea. I added a new file (test.html), committed it to the master, then tried to push to the clone's origin (`git push origin master`). No error was shown on push (i'd checked into a dummy branch on the origin repo so there would be no conflict), but the files aren't showing up on the remote server.

The intention here is to set things up so that i do most of my work locally, then push the change to the remote location where they can be server for UAT, after which they will be pushed again into production. But I can't seem to get past this initial configuration.

Much thanks in advance for any help here. Cheers!

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 is a free online book. I'd recommend the first 3 chapters at a minimum for anyone. So, you want to push your project to two different servers? I would look at the book's section 2.5 regarding adding remotes: http://git-scm.com/book/ch2-5.html

Comment: Thanks @jlents I've actually read through that already (this was how I was able to get as far as I have already.) unfortunately, it's not helping me understand why my files are not copying over when I push from the local to the remote.

Comment: I think the answer is right here: scm.com/book/ch2-5.html#Adding-Remote-Repositories . You can only have one remote location with the alias 'origin'. You need to add another remote (named whatever you want) and push it to that remote. At least, that's what I'm interpreting from your situation (that you want to have 2 remote locations you push stuff to).

Answer (score 0):

> I added a new file (test.html), committed it to the master, then tried to push to the clone's origin (git push origin master). No error was shown on push (i'd checked into a dummy branch on the origin repo so there would be no conflict), but the files aren't showing up on the remote server.

Since you checked into a dummy branch on the server, and you added test.html to master, of course you would not see test.html on the server: that file does not exist in the dummy branch, only on master. If you type `git checkout master` on the server, you should see the file.

However it seems like what you are trying to do is have the files in the working directory on the server automatically update when you push to it. Unfortunately, this is not possible. The working directory is only updated as the result of an explicit checkout or pull on the server.

What you probably want to do is investigate build server software that listens to a git repo, and does things (like copies the files to a web server) when there is a push. Or you may want to look into git hooks, which can also respond to pushes.

In any event, you will want your "main" git repo that you push/pull to/from to be a bare repository.